# Saved li data to browser not loading, only clearing

Tags: javascript, html, browser, save

I have inputs that create li's. Based on the two options users have (month / week), the dates on the titles of the input fields change to reflect the appropriate week of the year.

I am having trouble getting the data save and reload when the same option is reselected. Say I choose "January - Week 1" and enter "Hello". When I switch to February, any week, all data is erased. I wanted data to clear so there would be a fresh entry space when a new option was selected, but I also wanted the entries to be saved to their particular option choices. Right now, only clearing seems to be occurring.

Here is the HTML for one of the day entries:

```
 <div class="day scrollable" id="monday">
                <div class="span"><h3 class="day-title" data-day="1">Monday</h3></div>
                <input type="text" class="input">
                <button>
                    <img src="/Images/plus.png" id="add-button">
                </button>
                <ul class="list"></ul>
                 </div>
```

And here is the Javascript I've been trying to get my desired result:

```
const saveData = () = > {
  const dayElements = document.querySelectorAll('.day');
  const data = {};

  dayElements.forEach(dayElement = > {
    const month = document.getElementById('select-month').value;
    const week = document.getElementById('select-week').value;
    const dayIndex = dayElement.getAttribute('data-day');
    const key = `${month} - ${week} - $ { dayIndex }
    `;

    const liElements = dayElement.querySelectorAll('li');
    const values = Array.from(liElements).map(li = > li.innerHTML);

    data[key] = values;
  });

  localStorage.setItem('scheduleData', JSON.stringify(data));
};

const loadData = () = > {
  const savedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('scheduleData')) || {};
  const month = document.getElementById('select-month').value;
  const week = document.getElementById('select-week').value;

  const data = savedData[`${month} - $ { week }`] || {};

  const dayElements = document.querySelectorAll('.day');
  dayElements.forEach(dayElement = > {
    const dayIndex = dayElement.getAttribute('data-day');
    const key = `${month} - ${week} - $ { dayIndex }
    `;

    const values = data[key];
    if (values && values.length > 0) {
      values.forEach(value = > {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = value;
        dayElement.querySelector('ul').appendChild(li);

        let span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = "\u00d7";
        span.addEventListener(
            'click', (e) = > {
              e.stopPropagation();
              e.target.parentElement.remove();
              checkScroll();
              saveData();
            });

        li.appendChild(span);

        li.addEventListener(
            'click', () = > { li.classList.toggle('checked'); });
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the clearData() function to only clear the data for the selected month and week while preserving the day entries.

Here's the updated version of the clearData() function:

```js
const clearData = () => {
  const month = document.getElementById('select-month').value;
  const week = document.getElementById('select-week').value;
  const keyPrefix = `${month}-${week}`;

  const dayElements = document.querySelectorAll('.day');
  dayElements.forEach(dayElement => {
    const dayIndex = dayElement.getAttribute('data-day');
    const key = `${keyPrefix}-${dayIndex}`;

    if (dayElement.querySelector('ul').getAttribute('data-key') === key) {
      dayElement.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = '';
    } else if (key.startsWith(keyPrefix)) {
      // Clear the li elements for other days within the selected month and week
      dayElement.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = '';
      dayElement.querySelector('ul').setAttribute('data-key', key);
    }
  });

  saveData();
};
```

This will clear the data only for the selected month and week combination, while preserving the day entries within that combination.

Also call the loadData() function after updating the day titles in the selectMonth and selectWeek change event listeners, like this:

```js
selectMonth.addEventListener('change', () => {
  clearData();
  updateDayTitles();
  loadData();
});

selectWeek.addEventListener('change', () => {
  clearData();
  updateDayTitles();
  loadData();
});
```

if you load the data after clearing and updating the day titles, you ensure that the correct data is loaded for the selected month and week combination.